# cannot convert string to date

Tags: asp.net, string, date

Hello stack overflow residents! this is my first post and i'm hoping to receive some help.
I've searched but because I'm still very new, i was not able to full find/understand my answer.

I keep encountering this error:

> Message: Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid. File:
>   ~/reports/pendingshipments.aspx Function: btnExportXls_Click Stack
>   Trace: at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDate(String
>   Value) at reports_default.btnExportXls_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) in C:\Users\jet.jones\Documents\ERIRoot\ERITitan\ERITitan.ssa\Web
>   Application\reports\pendingshipments.aspx.vb:line 75

Here is my code:

on App_code

```
**Public Function Reports_PendingShipments(ByVal intClientID As Integer, ByVal strMinDate As Date?, ByVal strMaxDate As Date?, ByVal xmlSiteID As String) As DataTable
        '=================================================================================
        ' Author:       Jet Jones
        ' Create date:  2013.05.28
        ' Description:  Returns a data table with pending shipments for the sites specified
        '=================================================================================
        Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Titan").ToString)
        Dim cmdGet As New SqlCommand("spReports_PendingShipments", objConn)
        Dim parClientID As New SqlParameter("@ClientID", SqlDbType.Int)
        Dim parMinDate As New SqlParameter("@MaxDate", IIf(Not strMinDate.HasValue, DBNull.Value, strMinDate))
        Dim parMaxDate As New SqlParameter("@MaxDate", IIf(Not strMaxDate.HasValue, DBNull.Value, strMaxDate))
        Dim parSiteID As New SqlParameter("@Sites", SqlDbType.Xml)
        Dim objAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdGet)
        Dim objTable As New DataTable
        parClientID.Value = intClientID
        parMinDate.Value = strMinDate
        parMaxDate.Value = strMaxDate
        parSiteID.Value = xmlSiteID
        'set up the command object
        cmdGet.Connection = objConn
        cmdGet.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        'add the parameters
        cmdGet.Parameters.Add(parClientID)
        cmdGet.Parameters.Add(parMinDate)
        cmdGet.Parameters.Add(parMaxDate)
        cmdGet.Parameters.Add(parSiteID)
        'open the connection
        objConn.Open()
        'execute the query and fill the data table
        objAdapter.Fill(objTable)
        'return the data table
        Reports_PendingShipments = objTable
        'clean up
        objConn.Close()
        objConn = Nothing
    End Function**
```

my aspx.vb page calls this function this way (Get the values from the query):

```
objTable = Reports_PendingShipments(ucClientSearch.Value,
    txtMinDate.Text, txtMaxDate.Text, strSites)
```

I'm passing the variable strSites because the website permissions allow for users to have access to one or more site locations, and if a report is run and the user selects "All Sites" from the dropdown, I only want to send the sites they have permissions to via XML.

If I'm missing any information please let me know!
anyone's prompt response is so greatly appreciated.

Comment: Giving us a date format that you're trying to convert would be a start.

Comment: yes sir! user can enter dates in this format 5/30/2013

Comment: The error message is pretty specific.  Somewhere you have an empty string you are trying to make into a date...   What is the exact contents of line 75 in the source code?

Comment: Yes. the problem is that i don't get the error if the user enters dates. if they leave the date fields blank it tries to pass a blank string in as a date and i cant figure out how to solve that

Comment: What is the code on and around pendingshipments.aspx.vb line 75?

Comment: The error message seems to suggest the function with the problem is `btnExportXls_Click` but you seem to have given us a different function. Also it gives a line number and letting us know which line of the code you have given is that line would be useful...

Comment: this is line 75 on my aspx.vb page:

objTable = Reports_PendingShipments(ucClientSearch.Value,
    txtMinDate.Text, txtMaxDate.Text, strSites)

Comment: @JettyJetty: A good question should give the context. If you are trying to solve the problem of what to do when the user enters nothing then you should ask that. What you need to look into is validation. asp.net has validators built in that you could look into using or just do your own checks (eg if `datestring=""`).

Comment: thank you everyone for tolerating my badly formatted posts. i thought i did include validation in my app_code function but it doesnt seem to be working. and yes! context: how to i pass blank strings as dates??

Comment: @JettyJetty: Sparky seems to have roughly hit the nail on the head with his answer and his suggested solution. I think the problem is that we don't know where your line 75 is. You need to give us whichever method contains that I think.

Comment: It might be the problem due to change in regional setting of SQL server and your development environment. Please check if both are following same dateformat. Also check what happen if you select the date having less then 12 days like 12 Jan 2013 (01/12/2013).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code is expecting empty dates to be NULL, it doesn't check for empty strings.    You need something like this:

```
if len(strMinDate)=0 then
   strMinDate = "01/01/1980"
end
```

Not sure what you want to default the minimum date to, but you need to add code similar to the IF statement above

Be sure to add this code prior to using the variable a few lines later...

Comment: You are almost certainly right though I note that the problem doesn't look like it is in the above code so not the "strMinDate" variable above (which looks like it is confusingly actualyl a nullable date).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you adding MaxDate parameter twice:

```
Dim parMinDate As New SqlParameter("@MaxDate", IIf(Not strMinDate.HasValue, DBNull.Value, strMinDate))
Dim parMaxDate As New SqlParameter("@MaxDate", IIf(Not strMaxDate.HasValue, DBNull.Value, strMaxDate))
```

And moreover, then you setting parameters values wuthout check for HasValue:

```
parMinDate.Value = strMinDate
parMaxDate.Value = strMaxDate
```

Remove these lines and fix min date parameter name